# Nonlinear differential equation $y'^2-4xyy'+8y^2=0$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have a nonlinear differential equation $y'^2-4xyy'+8y^2=0$.
I tried setting $y=e^z$, which then simplifies the initial equation to $z'^2-4xz'+8=0$. I do not know how to take it from there, or if that is even a correct way to approach the problem.

Answer (score 2):

The last equation can be written as $(z'-2x)^2=4x^2-8$ and so $z$ must be a primitive of $2x+\sqrt{4x^2-8}$ or of  $2x-\sqrt{4x^2-8}$. The problem is if it is correct to say that all the solutions have the form $e^z$, for instance also $y=0$ is a solution of your equation. So it is more correct not to use the substitution, thus solving only the equation as a quadratic in $y'$.

Answer (score 1):

$\mathcal{Hint}$

Seeing this as a quadratic in $y'$ gives
$y'=2xy \pm y\sqrt{4x^2-8}$

Answer (score 1):

***Hint:***
$$y'^2-4xyy'+8y^2=0$$
$$\left ( \dfrac {y'^2}{y^2}\right)-4x \left (\dfrac {y'}{y}\right)=-8$$
$$(\ln y)'^2-4x (\ln y)'=-8 $$
$$u^2-4xu=-8$$
Complete the square:
$$u^2-4xu+4x^2=-4(2-x^2)$$
$$(u-2x)^2=4(x^2-2)$$
$$u=2x \pm2\sqrt {(x^2-2)}$$
Where $u=(\ln y)'$ .This is easy to solve. Note that $y=0$ is also a solution.

Comment: You've effectively re-derived what they had already done. If they knew how to solve it from here, they would have.

Comment: @AlexanderJ93 true but then with the quadratic formula op can solve it..I added some lines for more clarity.

Answer (score 0):

By the quadratic formula, $$y’=2y\left(x\pm\sqrt{x^2-1} \right) $$ This is variable separable. $$\int\frac{dy}{2y} = \int x\pm \sqrt{x^2-1} \ dx $$ For the square root, you can substitute $x=\sec\theta$ and you’ll get $$\frac 12\ln |y|=\frac{x^2}{2} \pm\left(\frac x2\sqrt{x^2-1} -\frac 12\ln|x+\sqrt{x^2-1} | \right) +C$$